# How can I access jQuery UI slider positions to make a calculation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, label

I have two sliders, one for the amount of cash to be borrowed and one for the number of days to borrow it. Correct interest calculations aside, I cant seem to make any sort of calculation within the function without breaking everything.

Here's a fiddle showing a working version of the sliders, but no calculation. At the bottom of the JS is a commented out version of what Im trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/P7TTa/4/

```
<script>
$(function() {
    // setup cash
    $( "#cashSlider" ).slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: "max",
        min: 10,
        max: 250,
        value: 40,
        step: 1,
        animate: true,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#cash" ).val( ui.value );
        }
    });

    // setup days
    $( "#daysSlider" ).slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: "max",
        min: 1,
        max: 30,
        value: 7,
        step: 1,
        animate: true,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#days" ).val( ui.value );
        }
    });

    $( "#cash" ).val( $( "#cashSlider" ).slider( "value" ) );
    $( "#days" ).val( $( "#daysSlider" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Oh lord, sorry that hasn't come up formatted properly!

Comment: What sort of calculation do you need ? As long as `#cash` and `#days` are livelly updated when you move the slides, why don't use them to make you thing ?

Comment: It would be an interest calculation, and the result displayed could be something like 1.01 * the amount+fee each day it is borrowed. The problem though is that I can't seem to work out how to do this without everything breaking!

Answer (score 0):

in each `slide` function, call a function that compute the interest.

```
...
animate: true,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#days" ).val( ui.value );
        $( "#result" ).val(computeInterest());
    }
...

function computeInterest(){
    if(typeof $("#days") != undefined && typeof $("#cash") != undefined){
        var result = //some computing...
        return result;
    }
    return 0;
}
```